# Creating Junit Runnable Jar

Tags: java, junit, junit4

My code below runs/works in eclipse just fine and execute a report. My problem is I cant create a runnable jar. I have searched the web and I see what it says:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {                    
       JUnitCore.main(
         "com.stackoverflow.MyTestSuite");            
}
```

So I know I have to have a Main class. However, I don't know how to implement it in my code my code is below:

```
//############ Automation using JUnit
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING) // this allows you to execute test in order 
public class adpOne {


    //Main Method calling individual methods from class [adpTwo.java]
    @Test
    public void bankRatePart1() throws Exception  {
    adpTwo m = new adpTwo();
    // m = short for method

    adpTwo.setUpBeforeClass();
    m.step01_ShouldGo2Website(); 
    m.step02_ShouldMoveToMortgages();
    m.step03_ShouldClickOnCalculators();
    m.step04_ShouldScrollDown(); 

    }


    // Main Method calling individual methods from class [adpTwo.java]
    @Test
    public void bankRatePart2() throws Exception  {
    adpTwo m = new adpTwo();

    m.step05_ShouldClickMorgageLoanPaymentCalc();
    m.step06_ShouldScrollDownCalcPage();
    m.step07_ShouldClearMortgageSendKeys();
    m.step08_ShouldSelectYearValue();

    }

    // Main Method calling individual methods from class [adpTwo.java]
    @Test
    public void bankRatePart3() throws Exception  {
    adpTwo m = new adpTwo();

    m.step09_ShouldSelectInterestRate();
    m.step10_ShouldButtonClick();
    m.step11_ShouldSlideMortgageSlider();
    m.step12_ShouldSlideYearsSlider();
    m.step13_ShouldSlideInterestSlider();
    m.step14_ShouldVerifyCalcutaion();
    m.tearDown();

    }

}
```

Also when I try using the main class I get errors from eclipse.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the error?